# How to sort an Excel array in place

Tags: excel, sorting, array-formulas

I'm populating an Excel array using an array formula and want the results to be sorted. If I attempt to sort (using data/sort) I get the error "You can't change part of an array". The only way I can sort it is by copying the array and pasting it as values, then sorting that copy.  Is there a better way.

Steps to replicate:

In a blank worksheet, select range A1:A10 and insert an array formula that gives numeric results, e.g. =RAND(). The range is populated with values. Try to sort the range using Data/Sort and you get the above error.

Comment: You'll need to change the array formula to return its results sorted

Comment: Thanks. Could you give an example of how I would need to change my existing {=RAND()} formula to do that?

Comment: If you have the new [Dynamic Array](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-in-non-dynamic-aware-excel-696e164e-306b-4282-ae9d-aa88f5502fa2) features, try `=Sort(RandArray(10,1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In place"? I doubt it's possible with excel function as it will cause self/circular referencing.

If you select "A1:A10" and enter an array(CSE) formula = Rand() then it can be sorted with following **Array (CSE)** formula in cell "D1" and copied down. This will sort the array in ascending order. To sort it in descending order replace ",1)%" with ",0)%"

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(SMALL(NPV(-RANK.EQ($A$1:$A$10,$A$1:$A$10,1)%,$A$1:$A$10)*100+ROW($A$1:$A$10),ROWS($A$1:A1)),NPV(-RANK.EQ($A$1:$A$10,$A$1:$A$10,1)%,$A$1:$A$10)*100+ROW($A$1:$A$10),0))
```

Reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61968559/9808063) from shrivallabha.redij

For **"In place"** array function refer to UDF below. Select "H1:H10" and enter **Array (CSE)** Formula `=SortRandArr(H1:H10,1)` for descending sort or `=SortRandArr(H1:H10,0)` for ascending sort.

```
Function SortRandArr(arrSizeRng As Range, Optional srtCriteria = 0)
'arrSizeRng is range of the same size of desired one dimensional array
'srtCriteria is criteria to sort; 0 or nothing for Ascending, Other digit for descending.
Application.Volatile
Dim Lb As Long, Ub As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim arr

ReDim arr(arrSizeRng.Cells.Count - 1)

For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
arr(x) = Round(Rnd(), 4)
Next

Lb = LBound(arr): Ub = UBound(arr)

If srtCriteria = 0 Then
    For i = Lb To Ub - 1
    For j = i + 1 To Ub
        If Val(arr(i)) > Val(arr(j)) Then
        strTemp = arr(i)
        arr(i) = arr(j)
        arr(j) = strTemp
        End If
    Next j
    Next i
Else
    For i = Lb To Ub - 1
    For j = i + 1 To Ub
        If Val(arr(i)) < Val(arr(j)) Then
        strTemp = arr(i)
        arr(i) = arr(j)
        arr(j) = strTemp
        End If
    Next j
    Next i
End If

SortRandArr = Application.Transpose(arr)

End Function
```

For one dimensional VBA sort referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60797214/9808063)

[image]

Comment: Marked as answer for earlier versions but dynamic array functions is probably the solution for latest version

Comment: Yes .. my is office 16 :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar and found this thread.  The solution I came up with is to add a helper column that references the array elements, then sort by that.  For example, if the array is in A1:A10, add a column Z1:Z10 with the formulas =A1 down to =A10 (not an array).  Then sort by column Z but don't include column A in the sort.  The array in column A gets sorted "in place".  Not sure if that will help in your situation.

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output for this approach?